# Applet mentioned in Griffiths' Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, education, specific-reference, software

In the book *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics* by David J Griffiths, a applet was mentioned in footnote 7 to better understand Example 2.1:

> ${}^7$This is nicely illustrated by an applet at the website www.phys.uri.edu/~yoon/deepwellmain.html

I have not been able to find the applet. Can anyone provide me an alternative URL?

Comment: What is Ex. 2.1?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the URL (now broken) that was printed in Footnote 7 of the book led to one of "Mark's Quantum Mechanics Applets".  [These applets survive at this webpage.](http://harfesoft.de/aixphysik/quanten/Mark/index.html)  The specific applet that Griffiths was referring to appears to have been the "Infinitely Deep Square Well" applet.

Comment: While checking this out I found another set of quantum mechanics visualizations.  I haven't checked the utility or quality:
https://www.st-andrews.ac.uk/physics/quvis/

Comment: Sadly, there is not a single modern web browser that still supports these Java applets. I was eventually able to run them using Appletviewer, but even then I couldn't actually see what was being visualized, I think cause for some reason it was drawing in white on white.

Answer (score 1):

A wonderful collection of physics applets (including the 1D infinite potential well quantum simulation) is available at falstad.com.  For the 1D well, see: http://falstad.com/qm1d/